# grouping on every label value

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe like this:

[image]

and i want after group by its should show aggregation on every label like this:

[image]

Is their any inbuilt function available for achieving this visualization.

Comment: Can you post the data as text instead of pictures? if you can put your input data (sample) & expected data (sample) you are likely to get very quick responses

Comment: you could try using the pivot_table() method on your dataframe

Comment: Pivot is not giving sum on parent elements.